# core binding to localhost instead of ip address

Tags: stellar-core

I have setup a stellar core in local. However when I start the core, it binds to local host. How can I bind it to ip address instead?

Answer (score 1):

Stellar-core has two interfaces, one is the public p2p port and the other is a http interface. The (admin/monitoring/info-) http interface is not supposed to be exposed to the public, so you might want to set some according firewall rules or set up a proxy before doing that.

However the configuration parameter to bind to any ipv4 address is: `PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=true`

Comment: but this is not recommended right?

Comment: Not as long as you can't ensure that anyone else can access it.